# why collection [Person.companies] was not processed by flush() when using session?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am using grails 1.1.1 and i got this error 
collection [Person.companies] was not processed by flush()

the configuration is as follow:
Person domain has many companies (Company domain)
while Company belongsTo Person

then in the controller I did like this

```
def person = session.person ; 
def jobs =  Job.findByPerson(person);
jobs.currentSalary = new BigDecimal(params.currentSalary);
... another code ... 

jobs.save(flush:true);
```

it produce the following error: collection [Person.companies] was not processed by flush()

I tried to change the first line from

```
def person = session.person;
to
def person = Person.get(session.person.id);
```

I read on the mailing list, someone said it related to searchable plugin but I am not using that one.

and it works ...

my question, why i cannot use session.person that contains the same object.

thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
def person = session.person;
```

with:

```
def person = session.person.attach();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when person.company was defined as a List rather than a Set or SortedSet.  In my case, I ended up having to change the compareTo function of Company so that SortedSet worked properly.  It seemed to be an odd interaction between these JIRAs 2986 and 4453 that I didn't have time to sort out.  The root problem involves some lazy loading of collections.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4453
(can only post one hyperlink)